# Order of members, order of derivation matters?

Tags: c++

Sometimes I have come across this issue that whenever I change the order of members, order of derivation in my C++ class the issue gets solved, crash gets fixed.

Recently I moved the position of a private member variable from a lower location to the top of my class and the error got fixed

Another time I had a class A:public B, public C. The moment I changed this to 
class A:public C, public B the crashing code started working. C is class containing virtual methods
and in the former case class A was not finding the method overriden in C but in the later it was able to find. Is this due to virtual pointer corruption? If so what has it got to do with order
of members? I know the memory layout changes when we change order of members but how do we debug such sort of issues because in VS2008 I could not find any indication as to why the crash was happening?

Note: Base classes B and C are totally independent and have no dependency on each other

Comment: The debugger must have told you *something* about the crash.

Comment: When you "fix" a crash by re-ordering members, you're most likely simply masking an existing memory corruption by making it manifest in a different way.

Comment: Can you post some example code to illustrate this?

Comment: The debugger just told me that the crash was happening when we were trying to access the virtual function through the base class pointer(In debug mode the function was not visible through the vfptr)

Comment: Time to post your 20-line narrowed-down testcase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base classes and member objects are initialized in declaration order, not the order of the initializer list.

If one of the bases receives a pointer to another base object and does anything more than just store the pointer for later use in its constructor, then the ctor will access an object that has not yet been constructed.

Using `/W3` warning level under MSVC/VS should give warnings both when `this` is passed to a base ctor pointing to a part of the object that is not initialized yet, and when the initializer list was shuffled to match declaration order.

Comment: The Base classes are TOTALLY independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities:

- You didn't recompile *all* your source, so your headers got out of sync;
- You have some *epic* Undefined Behaviour somewhere that's ruining everything.

Steps to debug:

- Run through a static analysis tool
- Full rebuild in debug mode
- Run through a debugger
- Run through a dynamic analysis tool

Comment: To be fair, it sounds like the OP is working under Windows ("VS2008"), so using Valgrind may be tricky!

Comment: OK, or the equivalent for poxier OSs

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: on the other hand, VS debugger is pretty nice.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: It's been a **long** time since I've used VS for anything serious.  Can it do the equivalent of Valgrind? (i.e. track dynamic memory allocation, etc.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: not that I know of. It is a nice "debugger", in that the display of the values is graphic (difference of GUI vs gdb).

Comment: "graphical debugging botched"

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you defined an array : int A[M]. 
M is less than you used in the code.
I also have this trouble today. 
I defined 
bool mMyArray[6];

However, in my code, I uses somewhere mMyArray[7] = false;